# How to assign a pointer to another pointer of different type

Tags: c, pointers, types, assign

```
unsigned int *ptr1;
int * ptr2;
```

while assigning ptr1 to ptr2 ,

```
*ptr1 = *ptr2;
```

the compiler throws error.

how to perform this assignment?

malloc of ptr1 is performed for 34 type unsigned int. ptr2 is has populated values.
This assigned has to be performed for 34 indexes.
say

```
for(i=0;i<34;i++)
{
*ptr1[i] = *ptr2[i] // this is the line where my compiler throws error.
}
```

Kindly help !!

Comment: Please supply language. Pointer casting is different in C / C++

Comment: How can this be done in C ?

Comment: If you are using the `array[index]` syntax you don't need that `*`, the subscript operator already dereferences.

Comment: What error does the compiler throw? Read it carefully and it can help you to understand the problem.

Answer (score 4):

```
*ptr1[i] = *ptr2[i];
```

is not valid. `ptr1[i]` is an `unsigned int`, and `ptr2[i]` is an `int`. The `*` unary operator can only be applied to pointers, not integers. It should be:

```
ptr1[i] = (unsigned int)ptr2[i];
```

Comment: In C you wouldn't (and shouldn't) cast when assigning to an unsigned. The conversion that has to be done, there, is well defined.

Comment: With the above change the compiler doesnot throw any error.but segmentation fault occurs at ptr1[i] = (unsigned int)ptr2[i];basically i want to copy/assign the contents of one pointer into another pointer.so that when i delete one pointer the entire contents of the other pointer are also deleted.is there any way i can do it ?

Comment: Copying a pointer doesn't make a copy of what it points to, you end up with two pointers to the same memory. So if you delete one of them, they're both pointing to deleted memory and you can't use either of them.

Answer (score 4):

Barmar's answer is correct. Here's another way to think about it.

```
*p[j]
```

is the same thing as

```
*(p[j])
```

which is the same thing as

```
*(*(p + j))
```

which is the same thing as

```
**(p+j)
```

and now it is clear that you are dereferencing *twice*. You intend to dereference *once*. Just remove the outer `*`.